# How can 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get' error be fixed

Tags: python-xarray, kaggle

I am building a simple neural network model using Weatherbench dataset in Kaggle environment using Jupyter Notebook.
Entry point error  occurs when I want to open the data.
what could be the issue and is there a way around it. The code and error pictures are below

I run into the error trying to open the data using xarray, after successfully downloading and unzip the dataset. I expect to assign the dataset to z500 variables so as to load it to memory for processing
Below is the code and the error message

## CODE

```
# Import packages

import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

## Load in the necessary python packages to train a neural network

import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow as tf

## Download data

try:
    !wget https://get.ecmwf.int/repository/mooc-machine-learning-weather-climate/geopotential_500_5.625deg.zip
except:
    !wget --no-check-certificate "https://dataserv.ub.tum.de/s/m1524895/download?path=%2F5.625deg%2Fgeopotential_500&files=geopotential_500_5.625deg.zip" -O geopotential_500_5.625deg.zip

## Unzip data

!unzip geopotential_500_5.625deg.zip

## Read data

z500 = xr.open_mfdataset('geopotential_500\*.nc', combine='by_coords').isel(time=slice(None, None, 24))
## Error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_23/3138247779.py in <module>
----> 1 z500 = xr.open_mfdataset('geopotential_500*.nc', combine='by_coords').isel(time=slice(None, None, 24))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in open_mfdataset(paths, chunks, concat_dim, compat, preprocess, engine, data_vars, coords, combine, parallel, join, attrs_file, combine_attrs, **kwargs)
    906         getattr_ = getattr
    907 
--> 908     datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
    909     closers = [getattr_(ds, "_close") for ds in datasets]
    910     if preprocess is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    906         getattr_ = getattr
    907 
--> 908     datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
    909     closers = [getattr_(ds, "_close") for ds in datasets]
    910     if preprocess is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in open_dataset(filename_or_obj, engine, chunks, cache, decode_cf, mask_and_scale, decode_times, decode_timedelta, use_cftime, concat_characters, decode_coords, drop_variables, backend_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    477 
    478     if engine is None:
--> 479         engine = plugins.guess_engine(filename_or_obj)
    480 
    481     backend = plugins.get_backend(engine)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/plugins.py in guess_engine(store_spec)
    108 
    109 def guess_engine(store_spec):
--> 110     engines = list_engines()
    111 
    112     for engine, backend in engines.items():

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/plugins.py in list_engines()
    103 @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)
    104 def list_engines():
--> 105     entrypoints = entry_points().get("xarray.backends", ())
    106     return build_engines(entrypoints)
    107 

AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched platforms to Google Colab instead of Kaggle and the issue got resolved. It seemed the issue was the platform.